# Guvnor Drools 5.6.Final : Not working dynamic update of knowledgebase when deploy latest rules using guvnor

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, guvnor

Same code is working when using Guvnor Drool 5.5, after I updated to drool 5.6.Final it stopped working of runtime update of knowledgebase.

```
KnowledgeAgentConfiguration kaconf = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgentConfiguration(); 
kaconf.setProperty( "drools.agent.scanDirectories","false" ); 
KnowledgeAgent kagent = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgent( name, kaconf );
// moniter KnowledgeAgent
kagent.monitorResourceChangeEvents(true);
kagent.addEventListener(new KBaseChangeEventListener());
kagent.applyChangeSet( ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("META-INF/ChangeSet.xml") );
startResourceChangeScannerService();
startResourceChangeNotifierService();
kbase = kAgent.getKnowledgeBase();
```

Please help me.

Comment: Do you get some specific error/exception?

Comment: No error. When using drools 5.5 & deploy new rule using guvnor, I got call into KnowledgeAgentEventListener's methods. But in case of drools 5.6, i didn't detect changes.